# Which keys to go up or down in GNOME Terminal

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

When I open GNOME Terminal I do not like to use mouse so I had trouble when I want to go upper in the page or go down the page . So is there any key switch for that in order to navigate the page without mouse? - I do not say navigate the window -

Comment: do you mean by using the arrow keys or "shift-pageup" & "shift-pagedown" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short and sweet...

the key combination <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page-Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page-Down</kbd> controls page scrolling in gnome-terminal

Comment: Gnome-terminal also supports Shift+Home and Shift+End to jump all the way to the start/end, and Ctrl+Shift+Up and Ctrl+Shift+Down to scroll by a single line.

Comment: Shift+Page-Up and Shift+Page-Down does not work here on Ubuntu 20.10 and GNOME 3.38. They just insert 9 and 3 respectively

Comment: That's a _REALLY_ odd behavior. You need BLOCK NUM activate for this to work. In fact, it is not Shift+Page-Up but rather Shift+Numpad9. If BLOCK NUM is deactivated, it won't work. Page Up doesn't do anything. Page Down insert `~`. Shift+Page Up and Shift+Page Down insert 9 and 3 respectively

Answer (score 3):

**Some more helpful key combinations**

[image]

source http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_02_02.html#tab_02_02

Comment: what a nice link :)

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard shortcuts for GNOME Terminal are described [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/adv-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en).

The shortcut you are looking for is under the heading "Other", and as such cannot be edited.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> should scroll up by one page.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> should scroll down by one page.

**WARNING**: Notice they will work **ONLY** if you have <kbd>Bloc Num</kbd> turned **ON**.

To check whether <kbd>Bloc Num</kbd> is on, you can press <kbd>Page Up</kbd>. If it types "9" is on, if it doesn't do anything is off.

If <kbd>Bloc Num</kbd> is *off*, these two shortcuts won't work.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> will just type the number "9"

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> will just type the number "3".